# from where rpm query search and from where yum list search

Tags: linux, admin

I did rpm -qa and didn't found the package but when when I did yum list I found the package. why so and which command is useful in finding the installed packages in Linux?

Comment: Which distribution ? Which version of the distribution ? Which package is not found by rpm but well with yum ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't use `yum` or `rpm` to handle package management on my machine (running Debian 10 currently with XFCE) but I use the command `apt list --installed` to check my installed packages.  Then you can `grep` for whatever specific stuff you are looking for.

You could also check out this article. It's well written and has a lot of good info.

https://itsfoss.com/list-installed-packages-ubuntu/